# Jquery datatable one time callback on initialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I've been using Jquery's datatable plugin for a while and came across an issue I am not sure how to resolve in a clean manner. I want to have a function callback similar to fnCallback() which only executes when the datatable is first initalized and the first page of data has been loaded in.

I have a situation where I want to wait until my datatable has been constructed to be able to customize some of the elements (add some custom classes to elements dynamically created by the plugin).

I could do something like this:

```
var isInitialized = false;
$("#completed-action-items-table").dataTable(
     "fnDrawCallback": function () {
         if (!isInitialized) {
            //do logic
            isInitialized = true;
         }
     });
```

But this seems ugly.

Any suggestions would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think yours may be the best technique, short of writing CSS selectors that target the elements you're interested in without adding extra classes.

Answer (score 0):

The original answer works but you may prefer this more idiomatic way:

```
if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#example')) {
  // Do something else since the dataTable's already initialized
}
else {
  // Initialize the dataTable
  table = $('#example').DataTable({
    paging: false
  });
}
```

Source: https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3

Answer (score 0):

I hope Exception Handling will work here. A simple `try-catch` block will help to avoid this `ReferenceError`

```js
let table = $("#table-id").DataTable({
    drawCallback: function () {
        try {
            // Try to access the table variable here
            let rowCount = table.data().rows().count();
        } catch (error) {
            // Do nothing in catch block: totally your wish
            console.log("Table is not initialized yet")
        }
    },
});
```